# How can i change the sample counts, or frequenze with gprof? 10.0 ms is too much ubuntu.c++

Tags: c++, opencv, profiling, profile, gprof

I 'm workin with eclipse, I wrote a c++ code with opencv library, when I profiled it he gives me 0% time,

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
  0.00      0.00     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  cvScalar(double, double, double, double)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00   _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN3Cam11getPositionEP9_IplImage
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Oeffnecamera(CvScalar, CvScalar)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Berechnepositon(CvScalar, CvScalar)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  handleVersionKratky(std::string)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Cam::getPosition(_IplImage*)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Cam::GetThresholdedImage(_IplImage*, CvScalar, CvScalar)
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::operator|(std::_Ios_Openmode, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

the problem is that 0.01 second it to much.
i profiled with:

```
g++ -pg Name.cpp
than ./a.out

tahn gprof -b a.out > a.txt
than cut a.txt.
```

How can I change the sample counts to I get 0.0001 second or how can I change the frequence

Comment: You said in your first edit that it's urgent. What exactly is the problem? If you need timing figures, you can just put `for(i=0;i<1000;i++){...}` around it, stopwatch it, and divide the resulting time by 1000. If `opencv` does any IO, be aware `gprof` will not measure it, because it's a CPU sampler. If you're looking at self time, be aware it's meaningless, because most functions spend most of their time in calling other functions or in I/O.

Comment: hi, the problem is that i have to look the time spending from each function in this code with gprof.  i need to now which funktion take the most of time and have to optimize it.

Comment: i can't work with the for(i=0;i<1000;i++){...} because i have a camcapture, it work only one time.i have to become a call graph to i can present it, i need the gmon.out file with each sample count as 10 microseconde

Comment: i have my Bachelor finale work from the university and i have to finisched it as soon as possible, thats why i need it.

Comment: You have my sympathy. Normally I do not criticize people, but professors who teach `gprof` and require their students to use it, to the exclusion of all other tools and methods, are not helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding with more information. In your case, I would recommend a good profiler, one that samples on wall-clock time (not just CPU time like `gprof`), that samples the whole call stack (not just the program counter like `gprof`), and that reports inclusive percent time by line of code (not just by function, like most profilers). One of them is [*Zoom*](http://www.rotateright.com/) which is not free, but you can use a trial copy. Remember you need wall-clock (not CPU) percent (not absolute), inclusive (not self), per line (not per function).

Many people think they are looking for a "slow function".
No. What you need to understand is in a more general sense, *why* is the program spending a large part of its time.
You can only get that information by looking at inclusive percent of wall-clock time by line of code.

Also, I would suggest that the output you get from a stack-sampler will give as good or better presentation than a call graph. Call graphs tend to have lots of irrelevant detail (boxes with low percent) etc.

Comment: Thanks You mike for your Answer, i have installed Zoom and i will work with it now, i hope it will help.i will write back weh i get it. best regards

Comment: hi again,i'm triing to profile a normal c++ code with zoom but i don't get it, it's work total differet as gprof or other profiler,i have read the zoom introduction but ther is no good information how to profile a normal c++ code, kann you help me about it?regards

Comment: You set it up to get stack samples while it's running. You can adjust the frequency of sampling. Once it has acquired a set of stack samples, it has a butterfly view for each function, with callers on one side and callees on the other. It can show you a line of code, and the inclusive percent time of that line of code. Ex: if there's a call to a function Foo inside function Bar, that call would have negligible self time, but if it is on 30% of stack samples, then that call (not the function, the function call) is responsible for 30% of the total time.

Comment: the problem is, where i have to run the code. i can't run it in zoom, like with other programm, example withe perf , i dd: perf record helloworld.cpp than perf record it. where i have to run the code with zoom, my c++ code it too fast. first i will try with a nomal halloworld.cpp when i get it i will run my cpp code. where i have to run the helloword.cpp do i have to run it in the Terminal? and than start the zoo gui or i can i start zoom in the terminal and start profiling? but then i cant run the code?